# inserting text in cell using inputbox and value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know how to use text which i have enter in input box to fill some cells depends of other cell value (in same row) and also need control that will check is there 19 chars entered in input box

this is code im using for input box

```
Sub BOP()
Dim poziv As String



poziv = InputBox(Prompt:="Unesi BOP", _
      Title:="Upisi Bop", Default:="Upisi Bop")

 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: `to fill some cells depends of other cell value ` - could you be a little more specific. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question needs some more clarification. To check length use:

```
If Len(poziv) = 19 Then
```